# JGit how do i get the SHA1 from a RevCommit?

Tags: jgit

This seems like an idiotic question, but I can't find documentation on it anywhere.

How do I get a the SHA1 of a RevCommit object?

Comment: I've never used Java before but I typed "jgit revcommit" into Google and found http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/revwalk/RevCommit.html then http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/AnyObjectId.html#getName()

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[`RevCommit`](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/revwalk/RevCommit.html) inherits from `AnyObjectId` which has a [`getName`](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/AnyObjectId.html#getName()) function.

> ### getName
>
> ```
> public final String getName()
> ```
>
> **Returns**:
>
> string form of the SHA-1, in lower case hexadecimal.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, there is also an `AnyObjectId::name()` method that returns the same as `getName()`.

Answer (score 3):

Do note that `getName()`only works with SHA-1 repositories: JGit does not yet work with [SHA-256 repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47838703/6309).

That is why, for instance, Git 2.30 (Q1 2021) does mark the tests that uses JGit not to run unless we are testing with ShA-1 repositories.

See [commit ea699b4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ea699b4adc6f3d79506c91fb6a6c59218bd36d09) (13 Nov 2020) by [SZEDER Gábor (`szeder`)](https://github.com/szeder).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d302170](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d3021700461e63ff12cf2d24500f0c61b2fbf5e0), 25 Nov 2020)</sup>

> ### [`t5310-pack-bitmaps`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ea699b4adc6f3d79506c91fb6a6c59218bd36d09): skip JGit tests with SHA256
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: SZEDER Gábor</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Taylor Blau</sup>

> In 't5310-pack-bitmaps.sh' two tests make sure that our pack bitmaps are compatible with JGit's bitmaps.
> Alas, not even the most recent JGit version (5.9.0.[202009080501](https://github.com/git/git/commit/202009080501)-r) supports SHA256 yet, so when this test script is run with `GIT_TEST_DEFAULT_HASH=sha256` on a setup with JGit installed in `PATH`, then these two tests fail.
>
> Protect these two tests with the SHA1 prereq in order to skip them when testing with SHA256.

Comment: does this stay true in 2022?

Comment: @shabunc Yes, recent commit [shows the skip is still in place](https://github.com/git/git/blame/93eb41e2403788fa9105211956e87b6b2c22c68c/t/t5310-pack-bitmaps.sh#L189).