# How to obtain the RevCommit or ObjectId from a SHA1 ID string with JGit?

Tags: sha1, jgit

This question is the inverse of this question: [JGit how do i get the SHA1 from a RevCommit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22276456/jgit-how-do-i-get-the-sha1-from-a-revcommit).

If I am given the SHA1 ID of a particular commit as a string, how can I obtain the `ObjectId` or associated `RevCommit` in JGit?

Here is a possible answer, which iterates through all `RevCommit`s:

```java
RevCommit findCommit(String SHAId)
{
    Iterable<RevCommit> commits = git_.log().call();    
    for (RevCommit commit: commits)
    {
        if (commit.getName().equals(SHAId))
            return commit;
    }    
    return null;
}
```

Is there anything better than this implementation above?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is probably easier to first convert the string into an `ObjectId` and then have the `RevWalk` look it up.

```java
ObjectId commitId = ObjectId.fromString("ab434...");
try (RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk(repository)) {
  RevCommit commit = revWalk.parseCommit(commitId);
}
```

Comment: The [jgit-cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook) has a ready-to-run snippet for this [here](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/api/GetRevCommitFromObjectId.java).

Answer (score 3):

Notice that [`RevWalk`](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.9.1.201712030800-r/apidocs/index.html) is now auto-closable, so you can also use the try-with-resources statement:

```
try (RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk(repository)) {
    RevCommit commit = revWalk.parseCommit(commitId);
}
```