# Get Commit of a particular SHA-1 in jGit

Tags: jgit

I have a SHA-1 of a newly cloned repository. I want the author indent of this SHA-1.

So I need to use RevWalk and iterate the whole repository? Or is there a `findXX` method or other code I can use to get the `RevCommit` or another object that has the PersonIdent?

What I tried:

```java
public void authorInfoOf(Repository repo, AnyObjectId head) {
    try {
        try (RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repo)) {
            ObjectDatabase db = repo.getObjectDatabase();
            ObjectLoader k = repo.newObjectReader().open(head);
            ObjectReader s;
            // repo.newObjectReader().open(head);
            ObjectStream st = k.openStream();
            // RevWalk rw2 = new RevWalk(k);
            RevCommit commit = null;// walk.parseCommit(ref.getObjectId());

            PersonIdent authorIndent = commit.getAuthorIdent();
            System.out.println("\nCommit-Message: " + commit.getFullMessage() + " " + authorIndent.getEmailAddress());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Authir info of Anybject id Err " + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to obtain the RevCommit or ObjectId from a SHA1 ID string with JGit?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755475/how-to-obtain-the-revcommit-or-objectid-from-a-sha1-id-string-with-jgit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
public RevCommit getCommit(String idString, Repository repository, Git git){
    try{

        ObjectId o1 = repository.resolve(idString);
        if(o1 != null){
            try( RevWalk walk = new RevWalk( repository ) ) {
                  RevCommit commit = walk.parseCommit( o1 );
                  PersonIdent ai = commit.getAuthorIdent();
                  System.out.println("bbb >>" + ai.getEmailAddress() + "|" + ai.getTimeZone()  + "|" + ai.getWhen() + ", ref :" + idString);
                  return commit;
                }
        }else{
            System.err.println("Could not get commit with SHA :" + idString);
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("err :" + e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `RevCommit` represents a particular commit in a Git repository. Use `RevWalk::parseCommit()` to obtain the `RevCommit` for a specific object id/SHA-1.

For example:

```java
try( RevWalk walk = new RevWalk( repository ) ) {
  RevCommit commit = walk.parseCommit( ref.getObjectId() );
}
```

`parseCommit` returns the matching commit object for the given `ObjectId`.

In order to convert a SHA-1 (string) into an `ObjectId`, use `ObjectId::fromString()`:

```java
ObjectId commitId = ObjectId.fromString( "ab434..." );
```

See also: [How to obtain the RevCommit or ObjectId from a SHA1 ID string with JGit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755475/how-to-obtain-the-revcommit-or-objectid-from-a-sha1-id-string-with-jgit)

In the above example, a `Ref` was used to reference the object id. `Ref`s represent named references to object ids like branches, tags, or special refs like HEAD. Repository::exactRef() can be used to resolve a string to a `Ref` object.

For example:

```java
Ref headRef = repository.exactRef( "HEAD" );
```

Comment: Yes know how to get for head,but can I use it to get a Ref to a Commit by Sha-1 like Ref r1 = repo.exactRef("0375381d0f467d55c832b50aca54ad16858baa8b"); - gives me a big fat null. How to get a ref using a SHA?